# What is the best Linux distribution for PHP programming?

Tags: php, linux

What is the best Linux distribution for PHP programming ?

Comment: Sorry, "what's the best" questions aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: the answer is all of them, of course

Comment: For programming I can highly suggest Fedora. It's quite up-to-date, they ship with Eclipse properly packaged (which you don't find often) and well, it's linux. Linux is great for PHP programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no best. 
Whichever distribution works for you and maintains the comfort is the best. 
You can try the popular ones:

1. [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com)
2. [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org)
3. OpenSuse

I personally use, **[Mint 12](http://linuxmint.com)**

Comment: according to my experience ubuntu is not good for programmers because you can use or perform action on only one terminal so redhat might be better option

Comment: What? Who said you can work around with single terminal? Sometimes, I happily work with around 10 terminals on my desktop spread across 4 workspaces. And 'terminal is just the utility which calls the shell which is **bash** by default on Ubuntu. I guess, Redhat has the same one.

Comment: i am telling on a single workspaces and have you ever tried to install two application  at a same time

Comment: On a single workspace, you can instantiate multiple terminals. 
Yeah, ofcourse, we can't install two(or more) applications at once, dpkg locks the lib during current installation which prohibits advancement of any other install. I don't know if this only prevails on debian based distros. Redhat deals with that?

Comment: yes redhat deals with that sir

Comment: so you can open multiple terminals in ubuntu but only when installing software is not the only thing you do in terminals. there! agreed and closed.